# Macro : edit macro to work in worksheet outside of workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using a macro which looks up from one sheet of the workbook to another sheet of the workbook and shows the result in the first sheet. This macro is present in all of my workbooks and basically I am copy pasting the same data in the second worksheet for all the files. This is becoming a time consuming activity as all these datas are huge and takes a lot of time to be opened and pasted.

I want the same macro to use a common file outside of the workbook the macro is present instead of the tab within the same file.

I am pasting the macro used below. Basically it looks up Product Type from the tab" Product Mapping" based on a particular ID and paste this in "Syn Data" tab. The macro is run from Syn Data Tab. I want this macro to look up from a file stored in a separate location so that I can remove the Product Mapping tab from the file. Please can anyone helpme with this.

```
Dim a, b, i As Long

a = Sheets("Product mapping").Range("A1:E" & LastRowMap).Value
b = Sheets("Product mapping").Range("B1:E" & LastRowMap).Value

'For lookup using ACID
Dim ProdMapDict As Object
Set ProdMapDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")      

'For lookup using ID
Dim ProdMapDict2 As Object
Set ProdMapDict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
    ProdMapDict.Item(a(i, 1)) = a(i, 5)
Next

For i = 2 To UBound(b, 1)
    ProdMapDict2.Item(b(i, 1)) = b(i, 4)
Next

'Lookup manual product type using ACID then ID

a = Sheets("Syn Data").Range("R1:T" & LastRow).Value

a(1, 3) = "Manual Product Type"

For i = 2 To UBound(a, 1)
    If ProdMapDict.exists(a(i, 1)) And a(i, 1) <> "" Then
        a(i, 3) = ProdMapDict.Item(a(i, 1))
    ElseIf ProdMapDict2.exists(a(i, 2)) And a(i, 2) <> "" Then
        a(i, 3) = ProdMapDict2.Item(a(i, 2))        
    Else
        a(i, 3) = "#N/A"        
    End If
Next

'Extract relevant columns from array into spreadsheet
Sheets("Syn Data").Range("DI1:DK" & LastRow).Value = a
Sheets("Syn Data").Range("BQ2:BQ" & LastRow).Value = Range("DK2:DK" & LastRow).Value
Sheets("Syn Data").Range("DI1:DK" & LastRow).Clear

MsgBox "Manual product type updated"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Put the worksheet "Product Mapping" into its own workbook, *together with the macro*.
2. Instead of Sheets("Product Mapping") say `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Product Mapping")`.

   Explanation: `ThisWorkbook` is always a reference to the workbook containing the macro. That's why the macro should be in the same book as "Product Mapping".
3. Have a variable to hold the reference to the workbook containing "Syn Data", and a variable to hold the reference to worksheet "Syn Data":

   ```
   Dim synDataBook as Workbook
   Dim synDataSheet as Worksheet

   For Each synDataBook In Workbooks Do
     On Error Resume Next
     set synDataSheet = synDataBook.Worksheets("Syn Data")
     If Not synDataSheet Is Nothing Then Exit For
     On Error Goto 0
   Next synDataBook
   ```

   Explanation: The macro runs from the workbook containing "Product Mapping". It must either look for the workbook containing "Syn Data", or else the user must take care that the workbook containing "Syn Data" is the `ActiveWorkbook`.

   If you are sure that the user can be certain that "Syn Data" is the `ActiveSheet` when the macro is invoked then you can say `set synDataSheet = ActiveSheet` instead of looking it up.
4. Use `synDataSheet` instead of Sheets("Syn Data").
5. You may want to check for errors by making sure that `synDataBook` is what is expected:

   ```
   If synDataBook Is Nothing Then
     MsgBox "Cannot find worksheet ""Syn Data""."
     Stop
   End If
   ```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this and also for the detailed explanation. I will try this out. But I wanted the Macro to stay in the original file with the "Syn Data" tab. Lets say the file name is 'Filewithmacro'. Right now Filewithmacro has 2 sheets,"Syn Data" and "Product Mapping". I want to move Product Mapping tab out of Filewithmacro into a common folder. Also, when I am referencing some file outside of the current workbook do I not need to mention the filepath and filename somewhere? I am sorry if these are very basic questions. Have just started using Macros.

Comment: (1) You need to use the full pathname when you are *opening* the workbook from VBA. (2) After you have opened it you refer to it without the path; that's why you are not allowed to open two workbooks with the same name even if they are in different directories. (3) You can adapt the example for the case where the macro is in the workbook containing "Syn Data": the worksheet "Syn Data" is `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Syn Data")`; and you would need to iterate over the collection `Workbooks` to find the workbook which contains the sheet "Product Mapping", or open it if needed.